# Create the same PNG with ImageMagick 2 times: Binaries differ

Tags: binary, imagemagick, version-control, png

I create two images that should be identical, but their binaries are different:

```
$ convert -size 1x1 xc:white out1/w.png
$ sleep 1
$ convert -size 1x1 xc:white out2/w.png
$ diff out1/w.png out2/w.png 
Binary files out1/w.png and out2/w.png differ
```

Probably because of a timestamp in embedded metadata.

**QUESTION**: How to make ImageMagick create a binary that will always be the same?

---

## Context

I have a big ImageMagick script that creates many images that are then saved to Git (because most developers don't have the environment necessary to run the script).

I often edit the script (ex:define a new image) and then run it to regenerate all images. But I don't want to have Git differences for images that have not changed.

Apparently some compression algorithms produce slightly different results on different architectures. Not a big problem since I always generate on the same machine. But even on the same machine, the files always all differ.

*ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2015-08-06, on Ubuntu 2015.10*

Comment: A self-contained example that people could test with would be useful.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, there is a self-contained example, and Nicolas' reason for putting the binaries under source control seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: The example does not require anything, it creates the images from scratch :-)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32251501

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Ok, noted.

Comment: Suggestion: put a `sleep 1` between the two converts so people can run it as a script.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I don't see what you mean... I already run this as a script, without sleep.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul With no `sleep`, I don't see a difference. With a `sleep 1`, I do.

Comment: Probably due to a timestamp then, interesting! :-)

Answer (score 5):

It should be possible to strip the timestamps, using `-define png:exclude-chunks=date,time`; but there's apparently [a bug in the PNG encoder](http://studio.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=28681).

If you can stage your modifications, one possibility would be to use `identify`'s signature to only replace an existing image if the pixel contents of the image change:

```
mkdir out
convert -size 1x1 xc:white out/w.png
if [ ! -f w.png ]; then
    mv out/w.png w.png
else
    if [ "$(identify -verbose w.png | awk '/ignature/ { print $2 }')" != "$(identify -verbose out/w.png | awk '/ignature/ { print $2 }')" ]; then
        mv out/w.png w.png
    else
        rm out/w.png
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Good find! Apparently someone has found the exact bug: http://studio.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=28681#p127760 so I guess the fix should be out soon? (I feel optimistic haha). The workaround is a good idea, I should try to make it easier to use for instance a bash convert_strip function.

Comment: Another option would be to strip the timestamps after image creation, e.g. with `pngcrush -rem time` (added bonus of further reducing size if possible).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  `-strip` option:

```
$ convert -strip -size 1x1 xc:white out1/w.png
$ convert -strip -size 1x1 xc:white out2/w.png
$ md5sum out1/w.png out2/w.png 
<...same data...> *out1/w.png 
<...same data...> *out2/w.png
```

EDIT:

It may have some bug in png-encoder, so if this method does not work, try one of these:

The `+set` option removes a particular information in generated file. Here, we remove the creation and modification dates.

```
$ convert +set date:create +set date:modify -size 1x1 xc:white out1/w.png
$ convert +set date:create +set date:modify -size 1x1 xc:white out2/w.png
```

or (second form, test to choose the one works for you)

```
$ convert +set date:create +set modify-date -size 1x1 xc:white out1/w.png
$ convert +set date:create +set create-date -size 1x1 xc:white out2/w.png
```

source: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Comment: Adding -strip does not help here, strangely. I get different md5sums. Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: What gives you the diff on hexdumped files? On my side (imagemagick 6.8.8-10) the first images differ on the creation and modification date (`extDate` fields) the images generated with `-strip` do not have  these fields.

Comment: In light of the bug discussed in the other answer, you getting the same binary is quite a wonder, maybe your computer is fast and by chance you got the two same timestamps?

Comment: No, I analysed the generated files with hexdump and I see that the extDate fields where removed (and the files where smaller). A tips could be to remove dates with another method: `+set date:create +set date:modify` or `+set create-date +set modify-date` (I see these both examples that do not work for me)

Comment: This tip sounds interesting, could you please add to your answer the command line to generate the image using this tip? Thanks!

Comment: For dates and times I get the impression `+set` resets them to defaults instead of removing them entirely. At least `diff -u <(identify -verbose out1/w.png) <(identify -verbose out2/w.png)` still shows them present and different for me (along with `png:tIME`).

Answer (score 1):

convert option `-define png:exclude-chunks=date,time` works as expected and creates always the same target binary file for "ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-11-11" (`convert -v`).